# Different AdMob Ad Units ID in different Activities? Increase match rate?

Tags: java, android, admob

My app contains **only banner ads** in different activity (4 Activity).
So my doubt is,

- Can i use one Ad Unit ID for all banner ads?

Or

- Different ad unit for each activity.

What is the most suitable and **increase match rate?**

(5000 – 7000 impression per day, **Match rate 35 – 45 %**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is advisable to have different ad units for different ad spots. 
As it'll greatly help you later in reporting purposes and at time in debugging too.

Also, the match rate is not affected by this factor if you use just one ad unit or different.